# .Net Core - Method Create Error NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There are already some questions about this problem, but none of them actually solved my problem.

I'm trying to create the Create method of the Student.cs entity, but when I access the create url, this error appears, I really do not know how to solve it.

AlumniController.cs

line error: 32 var teachers = await _contextProfessor.FindAllAsync ();

Image error

[image]

Code

AlunoController.cs

```
public class AlunosController : Controller
    {
        public readonly AlunosService _contextAluno;
        public readonly ProfessorService _contextProfessor;
        public readonly TurmasController _contextTurma;

        public AlunosController(AlunosService contextAluno)
        {
            _contextAluno = contextAluno;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var lista = await _contextAluno.FindAllAsync();
            return View(lista);
        }

        //GET
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var professores = await _contextProfessor.FindAllAsync();
            var turmas = await _contextTurma.FindAllAsync();
            var viewModel = new AlunoViewModel {
                Professores = professores,
                Turmas = turmas
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

Turma.cs

```
public class Turma
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Curso { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; } = new List<Aluno>();

        public Turma()
        {
        }

        public Turma(int id, int numero, string curso)
        {
            Id = id;
            Numero = numero;
            Curso = curso;
        }
    }
```

Professor.cs

```
public class Professor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; } = new List<Aluno>();

        public Professor()
        {
        }

        public Professor(int id, string nome, string email, string telefone)
        {
            Id = id;
            Nome = nome;
            Email = email;
            Telefone = telefone;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Code Complete [HERE](https://github.com/renanosoriorosa/coreSchool-simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_contextProfessor` is null.  You will need to set it in the constructor of `AlunosController`.

```
public AlunosController(AlunosService contextAluno, ProfessorService professorService)
{
    _contextAluno = contextAluno;
    _contextProfessor = processorService;
}
```

Comment: I do it now, but right now i have other problem "InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have not assigned objects to `_contextProfessor` and `_contextTurma` fields, so you will naturally get a `NullReferenceException` if you try to refer to their methods and properties. So, firstly, you need to inject `ProfessorService` and `TurmasController` into controller constructor.

But for injection to be successfull, you need to specify the dependecies in your Startup class ConfigureServices method, otherwise the dependecy won't be able to be resolved an `InvaidOperationException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to include that service in the call in the constructor

```
    public AlunosController(AlunosService contextAluno, ProfessorService contextProfessor)
                                                       //^^^^
    {
        _contextAluno = contextAluno;
        _contextPrefessor = contextProfessor;
    }
```

DI bit you a little.  just because you add the one context to the constructor doesn't mean the others are instantiated for free.

Comment: I do it now, but right now i have other problem "InvalidOperationException"

Comment: New problem new question